# error grabbing ad code from database using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to grab ad code from my database and `echo` it on to the page, but for some reason it is not showing up?

```
$getad = ("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE place='non-mobile' AND who='adbrite' ");

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getad))
{
$code = $rows['code'];
}
$ad1 = $code;
```

later down the page i print it like this.

```
<?php print $ad1 ?>
```

Comment: There is no mysql_query. Any error?

Comment: What error do you got? Please post it.

Comment: OK, I suggest you to enable error reporting

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't actually execute the query, you just have saved it in a variable ($getad) and then try to do a fetch af an array containing a string as I see it. If I remeber correctly you have to save you query in a variable, as you did, and then type

```
$getad = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE place='non-mobile' AND who='adbrite' ";
$q = $db->query($getad);

// generate results:
while ($q->fetchInto($row)) {
    //display or store
}
```

You should also include checks, for example that this code has extracted at least one row, or that database connection is working, etcetera.